# How to display my android phone app on my laptop

Tags: android

I want to start doing demos/training of my android app to my customers. Is there anyway i can connect the phone to my laptop and what ever i do on the phone appears on the laptop screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [androidscreencast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/)

Actually I'm using it for my demoes (also remote demoes). Refresh is not so high, but it works, and it's free, and zero config to make it works!

You cannot remotely control your device, but everything on device screen, will appear also on connected pc screen.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to show application snap then you can take the current screen snap from `DDMS -> Devices -> Screen Capture`
2. Video capturing of application is not possible.

Comment: hi thanks for that. Im not looking to capture video just a remote viewer to save everyone cramming round my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can run an emulator and then use a screen capture device to record what is happening on the screen.

You can use something like http://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some apps out there that do continues screencaptures, but the framerate is limited to like 4 fps. There isn't really yet a good way to do this. Maybe if your phone has a HDMI connector?